# Что за куча в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать что то типо лаунчера(tk только начал изучать). Когда нажимаешь кнопку начать перекидывает на мусорку (изображение ниже) Как сделать НЕ кривой лаунчер?(пока выставляются только кнопки, а потом привязка к ним)

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import time
window = Tk()
window.title("Кто я")
window.geometry('1280x720')
from tkinter import *


def menu():
    lbl.configure(text="Команды:")
    lbl.grid(column=10, row=0)
    btn = Button(window, text="Модуль вк", command=Vk())
    btn.grid(column=20, row=1)
    btn = Button(window, text="Модуль приложений", command=open())
    btn.grid(column=30, row=2)
def Vk():
    lbl.configure(text="Модуль вк:")
    lbl.grid(column=10, row=0)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест1", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=20, row=1)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест2", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=30, row=1)
def open():
    lbl.configure(text="Модуль приложений:")
    lbl.grid(column=10, row=0)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест1", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=20, row=1)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест2", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=30, row=1)

lbl = Label(window, text="Добро пожаловать!", font=("Arial Bold", 50))
lbl.grid(column=10, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text="Начать", command=menu)
btn.grid(column=10, row=3)

window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно убрать вызов (command=Vk`()`) при присвоении комманд потому что они сразу открываются (пытаясь вычислить свое значение), для того чтобы не прыгала разметка для лейбла добавил `columnspan=40` - занять столько-то колонок , `width=30` - ширина,  `anchor="w"` - прижать к левому краю

*значения нужно еще подбирать для нужного эффекта*
([может быть полезным](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/grid))

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import time
window = Tk()
window.title("Кто я")
window.geometry('1280x720')
from tkinter import *


def menu():
    lbl.configure(text="Команды:", width=30,  anchor="w")
    lbl.grid(column=10, row=0, columnspan=40)
    btn = Button(window, text="Модуль вк", command=Vk)
    btn.grid(column=20, row=1)
    btn = Button(window, text="Модуль приложений", command=open)
    btn.grid(column=20, row=2)

def Vk():
    lbl.configure(text="Модуль вк:", width=30, anchor="w")
    lbl.grid(column=10, row=0, columnspan=40)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест1", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=30, row=1)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест2", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=30, row=2)

def open():
    lbl.configure(text="Модуль приложений:", width=30,  anchor="w")
    lbl.grid(column=10, row=0, columnspan=40)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест3", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=30, row=1)
    btn = Button(window, text="тест4", command=menu)
    btn.grid(column=30, row=2)

lbl = Label(window, text="Добро пожаловать!", font=("Arial Bold", 50) , width=30,  anchor="w")
lbl.grid(column=10, row=0, columnspan=40)
btn = Button(window, text="Начать", command=menu)
btn.grid(column=10, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```